# enable or disable button based on comparing textboxes values of gridview in c#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, gridview

Hi I'm new to javascript and c#.
Correct me if anywhere I'm wrong.

Here is my `gridview` code.

```
     <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" CssClass="table table-hover table-bordered" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowFooter="True" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
        <Columns>
          <asp:BoundField DataField="AvlQty" HeaderText="Available" ItemStyle-Width="35" >
<ItemStyle Width="35px"></ItemStyle>
            </asp:BoundField>


<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Qty" ItemStyle-Width="70">
                <ItemTemplate>                
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxQty" onkeyup="Calculation(this)" CssClass="txtQty" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SelQty") %>' MaxLength="5" Width="45"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBoxQty" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                 <asp:regularexpressionvalidator ID="revAvailablePeriod" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Must > 0" ForeColor="Red" controltovalidate="TextBoxQty" validationexpression="^[1-9][0-9]*(\.[0-9]+)?|0+\.[0-9]*[1-9][0-9]*$" setfocusonerror="true" validationgroup="AddAssests" xmlns:asp="#unknown"></asp:regularexpressionvalidator>
              <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server" ValueToCompare='<%# Eval("AvlQty") %>' ControlToValidate="TextBoxQty" ForeColor="Red"
ErrorMessage="Must < Available" Operator="LessThan" Type="Integer"></asp:CompareValidator>

                </ItemTemplate>

<ItemStyle Width="70px"></ItemStyle>
            </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns> 
</asp:GridView>

<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Enabled="false" Text="Place Order >>" CssClass="btn btn-info" OnClick="Button2_Click" />
```

Now if quantity is greater than available quantity for every row of `gridview`, than button should be disabled else button should be enabled.

I want to implement this using a javascript function.
Anyone can help me with this?

I wrote this function but don't know when to call and how to call ..
This is what i've done so far..

```
 function Calculation() 
 {
   var grid = document.getElementById("<%= GridView1.ClientID%>");
         var counter = 0;
         for (var i = 1; i < grid.rows.length ; i++) {
             var txtAvl = grid.rows[i].cells[3];

             var qty = grid.rows[i].cells[5];
             if (txtAvl.value >= qty.value && qty.value > 0)
             { counter++; }
             else
             { document.getElementById('Button2').disabled = true; }

         }
         if (counter == grid.rows.length)
             document.getElementById('Button2').disabled = false;

 }
```

Comment: Post your code in the question as update.

Comment: I added the javascript function code @DylanCorriveau as you asked..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onkeyup` function is enough to call this `javascript` validation. I have slightly changed your script and its working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function Calculation() {
            var grid = document.getElementById('GridView1');
            var counter = 0;

            for (var i = 1; i < grid.rows.length; i++) {

                var txtQty = document.getElementById('GridView1_ctl0' + (i + 1) + '_TextBoxQty'); //TextBox control

                if (txtQty != undefined) {

                    var qty = txtQty.value;
                    var txtAvl = grid.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML;

                    if (txtAvl >= qty && qty > 0) {
                        counter++;
                    }
                    else {
                        document.getElementById('Button2').disabled = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (counter == grid.rows.length - 2)
                document.getElementById('Button2').disabled = false;
        } 
    </script>
```

You have to update with the correct IDs for `Gridview` and `TextBox` accordingly. Hope this helps.

Comment: ..I tried ,what you said but function in script isn't working , I called funciton in textbox like this      <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxQty" onkeyup="Calculation()" CssClass="txtQty" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SelQty") %>' MaxLength="5" Width="45"></asp:TextBox>

Comment: @RajParekh Have you changed the GridView ID and TextBox ID as in your html?

Comment: ya @Selva TS ,I changed it to GridView1 and TextBoxQty.

Comment: What about the Column order? Have you tried to debug in Chrome/Firebox  Console?

Comment: ya i changed the column order too.I'm not getting one thing ,what (i+1) does in textbox control you have added.

Comment: Gridview automatically generating TextBoxIDs. Its not looks like what in design time. So just run your application and right click on your browser => select View Source => Navigate to the Gridview and look the TextBoxIDs. Based on the number generation, you have to add (i+1) or i.

Comment: I changed it to 'GridView1_' + 'TextBoxQty_' + (i - 1) because it generates id like id="GridView1_TextBoxQty_0"

Comment: I think now you got it.

Comment: Is it due to header and footer ?

Comment: Yes. Basically Gridview is a table and it has Header and Footer rows. So we need to remove them from the iteration.